# Conditional Change in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to change the column days (which is a datetime column)  conditional on the indicator column, i.e. when indicator is equal to either DTM or AMC, I would like to add 1 day to the days column.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [1, 2, 3],
            'indicator': ['BMO', 'DTM','AMC']})
```

So the result looks like this:

```
   days indicator
0     1       BMO
1     3       DTM
2     4       AMC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` with `isin`:

```
df['days'] = np.where(df['indicator'].isin(['DTM', 'AMC']), df['days'].add(1), df['days'])

   days indicator
0     1       BMO
1     3       DTM
2     4       AMC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [boolean mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['days'] += (df.indicator.eq('AMC') | df.indicator.eq('DTM'))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   days indicator
0     1       BMO
1     3       DTM
2     4       AMC
```

As an alternative you could use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['days'] += df.indicator.isin(('AMC', 'DTM'))
print(df)
```

You can add the boolean mask directly because in Python, booleans values are integers `(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['days']=df['days'].mask(df['indicator'].isin(['DTM','AMC']),df['days']+1)
```

or [Series.where](http://%20%20%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['days']=df['days'].where(~df['indicator'].isin(['DTM','AMC']),df['days']+1)
```

---

**Output**

```
#print(df)

   days indicator
0     1       BMO
1     3       DTM
2     4       AMC
```

Comment: Also, very useful, adding this to my cheat list, thanks!!